# Android - Positioning elements inside <merge /> tag

Tags: android, android-layout

I've just learned about the `<merge />` tag and I'm trying to **position** the elements inside it as I was in a `RelativeLayout` container. 
 Nothing, except `layout_gravity`, seems to be working. 
What am I doing wrong ? 
**Thx** anticipately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a workaround by using `tools` namespace.

You need to create a second layout file like this:

```
<!-- linear.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/merged"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can go ahead and use the `showIn` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="@layout/linear"> <!-- HERE the fun stuff -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"/>
</merge>
```

Doing so, the items will be displayed like if it was a `LinearLayout` and the same applies to every other layout type.

Comment: Great @David, what you suggested is working like a charm ...
Now there's a little problem: instead of the LinearLayout I'm using a RelativeLayout, and in the merged sub-layouts everything looks good. The problem is that now what's not working is the root layout itself (in the example linear.xml). I'm including 3 layouts and I'm trying to position them in a list style, but when I'm using layout_below nothing is happening. What should I do ?

Comment: Try setting height & width on the `include` tag, but I don't know a solution from the top of my head. if you can't get it to work you should open a new question with more details.